# MYSQL RBR Replica DB - Alternative for triggers

Tags: mysql, triggers, row, replication

We have a replica Mysql 8.0 DB, created/updated using ROW BASED Replication.

We would like to create BEFORE INSERT triggers on some of the replica db tables (triggers that do not exist on the source db) but this is not possible as it is RBR and triggers do not fire on ROW INSERTS.

MariaDB allows this with the slave_run_triggers_for_rbr global variable, does MySQL have something equivalent? (based on my research the answer is no.)

Is there an alternative way to achieve the same results from the triggers?

This could also be possible if can we create a new STATEMENT BASED replication, using the replica db as a source and create the triggers on the new replica db. Would this work?

Thank you.